# Причина javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, криптография, openssl, криптопро

Есть веб-приложение, крутящееся на JVM.

Возникла необходимость интеграции с сторонней системой.

И все вроде бы ничего, но при подключении на продуктивный контур, возникает следующее исключение

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Я уже спрашивал это [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056264/exception-in-thread-main-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-a).

Но данное исключение может быть по множеству причин.

Сертификаты в `cacerts` установлены, однако, ошибка не ушла.

Долго думая, я пришел к выводу, что это из-за того, что на продуктивном контуре стоит SSL сертификат с ГОСТ шифрованием.

Прикол в том, что если установить эти сертификаты на локальную машину Windows   в хранилище сертификатов и попытаться зайти на продуктив через IE, то все работает. Заходим через хром - видим.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Адрес прода совсем не секрет - http://egrz.ru/ и тык на личный кабинет

Т.е. когда мы пытаемся обратиться по адресу, если `Cipher suites` клиента не содержит `Cipher suite` сервера, мы получаем исключение.

Мои Ciphers(ничего, содержащего "GOST" нет):

```
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

Поправьте, если неправ.

Но как все-таки обойти это?

Возможно, можно попробовать через OpenSSL. [Тут](https://beldmit.dreamwidth.org/842550.html) обсуждается данная тема. Но вот беда - интеграцию Java и OpenSSL (чисто для создания SSL подключения) я не представляю.

Возможно, КриптоПро JCP реализует данные `Cipher suites` (вплоть до новых ГОСТов, вплоть до кузнечика), но денег в компании нема. Хотя мб и раскошелимся.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Если кто-то решил это при помощи КриптоПро JCP, то у меня всего-лишь один вопрос - есть ли там методы, которые помогут переопределить создание SSL подключения в Apache HTTP client? Кода очень-очень-очень много, переписывать все очень не хочется (первоначально все писалось для тестового контура, в котором вообще ssl нет).

А так же есть ли другие способы реализации и правильны ли мои догадки по поводу `ciphers`?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, но прямого решения (без установки стороннего софта) я не нашел. Однако способ обойти все таки есть (попробуйте, возможно хотя бы поймете в чем проблема):

1. На машине с JVM ставите [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Запускаете Fiddler
3. Заворачиваете трафик вашего приложения в Fiddler любым из
   [способов](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp)

В результате трафик вашего приложения будет идти через прокси Fiddlerа и выглядеть как "от браузера". Вместо фидлера (его основное назначение - дебаггинг) вы можете использовать любое похожее ПО, главное чтобы трафик шел через прокси.

Comment: Вы решили это при помощи КриптоПро JCP? Легко ли настраивать TLS? И можно ли как-то "подружить" Http Apache Client с ней? (имею в виду каждый запрос обернуть таким образом, что если мы идем на ГОСТ сервер, то используем КриптоПро TLS, иначе - стандратную реализацию Java SSL (встроена в Apache Http Client) )

Comment: Не, у нас не КриптоПро убивал трафик а другое похожее ПО, но суть проблемы та же. Я думаю вам стоит пнуть поддержку КриптоПро JCP, кроме них никто не знает как оно работает.